# Wordpress - Force 404 Errors in Htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

My website got hacked a few weeks ago and now I'm on the stage of removing all spammy links from my page. Some of them are 301 redirects to legit webpages of my site, which is affecting my SEO.

Example:

- `www.example.com/?attachment_id=93` (showing in Google results as spam) ---> `www.example.com/` (legit page).
- `www.example.com/z` (showing in Google results as spam) ---> `www.example.com/zlatni-rat-...` (legit page).

However, I'm not sure how to put this in `.htaccess`. Everytime I try something, my whole website gets a 404 error or the images don't appear, etc.

Here's what I've tried

1. Add this on the bottom of the file (which does not work):

   ```
   ErrorDocument 404 /z
   ErrorDocument 404 /?attachment_id=93**
   ```
2. Add the following within the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` code tags.

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   ....
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?attachment_id=93|z)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]   
   </IfModule>
   ```

This makes the entire website not to work!

I appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: Bruno i am unsure what you can do in .htaccess as those links are pointing to your domain exactly. however i would suggest taking on this plugin "Broken Link Checker" it will check all links in all your posts and you can simply unlink the ones that have a redirect

Comment: Are you suggesting that `www.example.com/?attachment_id=93` (invalid URL?) is currently _redirecting_ to `www.example.com/`? (If you've "fixed" the hacked site then it shouldn't be redirecting still? Unless you are seeing a cached redirect?)

Comment: @w3dk that's what I'm thinking now. If I had 100% cleaned the site, this shouldn't be happening! I will need to investigate further. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ErrorDocument 404 /z
> ```

The `ErrorDocument` defines a custom error document, so this is indeed invalid. But this is not needed, if you just want to reject spammy/invalid URLs.

> Add the following within the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` ...

You also need to place these directives *before* your existing WordPress directives. Apart from being wrong, if you place them after the WordPress front controller they will never be processed anyway.

However, if you have already "fixed" your hacked site then these URLs (presumably invalid) should not be redirecting and they should already be resulting in 404s? If you are still seeing a *redirect* then this might be a cached redirect from your browser cache.

Anyway, in order to get Google to drop these URLs quicker from the search results then it would perhaps be better to return a 410 Gone instead. With the two examples in your question, you will need two rules in `.htaccess`. Something like the following:

```
# www.example.com/?attachment_id=93
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^attachment_id=93$
RewriteRule ^$ - [G]

# www.example.com/z
RewriteRule ^z$ - [G]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked like a charm!

Interesting point you mentioned though: I have clean installed my WP and all my spam scans are OK. However these 301 redirects are still happening which now makes me think there's something still in there... I've done it in anonymous mode so it shouldn't be browser cache. 

Thanks again for you help!

Comment: Yes, anon. mode should avoid the cache (unless it's been left open?) - 301s are certainly cached _hard_ by the browser.

Comment: If this answered your question then please mark it as accepted to remove it from the unanswered question queue. You can also upvote answers you find useful once you have 15 rep points. Thanks, much appreciated. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: thanks. It's been months now and I'm using anonymous mode in my browser, so I don't think is a cache problem. Thank you!!